# Function not doing anything after clicking on button (aspx page)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have problem with buttons, I typed alert("") to be sure if it enters to function or not,I discovered that it enters into function after I click on button and the alert works fine but, anything else inside function does not work neither ajax nor any simple jquery code. I will add the code to be more clarified.

for example these buttons below

```
<button type="button" id="submitX" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" id="cancelX" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
```

This javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#cancelX", function (event) {
          alert('cancel function');
            window.location.href = "www.test.com";
         });
    $(document).on("click", "#submitX", function (event) {
           alert('submit function');

var Details  = $('#Detail').summernote('code');
var params = [];
params.push({ name: "CreatedBy", value: $('#Email').val() });
params.push({ name: "Detail", value: Details});
var apiURL = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/api/Submit/") %>";
$.ajax({
url: apiURL,
data: params,
type: "POST",
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
window.location.href = "www.test.com";
},
error: function (err) {
swal({
text: "An error occured.",
icon: "error"
});
}
})


  });
    });
```

why are both buttons or functions not working properly ? did I do anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `document.ready()` function on click event of cancel and submit button.Use below syntax:

```
 $("#id_name").click(function (event) {
      ..//Code
 });
```

And also remove type submit on which is given in submit button.Just make it simple button.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response I fixed the issue by replacing <button> tag with <input> then it worked

Answer (score 0):

try changing your 'button' tag to 'input' tag as you are using the type attribute.

Hope it works.